# What are the callbacks in ReactTransitionGroup hooks?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

React.js offers a low level API for animations called [ReactTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup). In the docs it is stated that for the hooks `componentWillAppear`, `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave`, a callback is passed as an argument.

My question is, what exactly is this callback and how it gets passed to those hooks, the docs aren't saying anything about those callbacks except that the animation is delayed until they get called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, I am also still learning ReactJS so there is a possibility that I could be wrong in my approach and what not. Apologies in advance for that.

Open your Developer Tools' `console` window and analyse **[this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/h68s0zod/)** example that I just made. Observe the sequence with which the callbacks get called.

I am using [`TweenMax`](http://greensock.com/gsap) to do some animations to a box to make it appear or disappear upon clicking of a button.

The **[Low-level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup)** exposes quite a few useful callbacks for us to utilise. Shared example demonstrates the use of these callbacks.

***JavaScript:***

```
var ReactTransitionGroup = React.addons.TransitionGroup;
var MyBox = React.createClass({
    show: function(callback){
        var node = React.findDOMNode(this);
        TweenMax.fromTo(node, 2, { width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: '#0cc', scale: 0.2, opacity: 0, rotation: -180 }, { width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: '#0cc', scale: 1, opacity: 1, rotation: 0, ease: Expo.easeInOut, onComplete: callback, onCompleteScope: this });
    },
    hide: function(callback){
        var node = React.findDOMNode(this);
        TweenMax.to(node, 2, { width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: '#cc0', scale: 0.2, opacity: 0, ease: Expo.easeInOut, onComplete: callback, onCompleteScope: this });
    },
    componentWillAppear: function(didAppearCallback){
        console.log('MyBox.componentWillAppear');
        this.show(didAppearCallback);
    },
    componentDidAppear: function(){
        console.log('MyBox.componentDidAppear');
    },
    componentWillEnter: function(didEnterCallback){
        console.log('MyBox.componentWillEnter');
        this.show(didEnterCallback);
    },
    componentDidEnter: function(){
        console.log('MyBox.componentDidEnter');
    },
    componentWillLeave: function(didLeaveCallback){
        console.log('MyBox.componentWillLeave');
        this.hide(didLeaveCallback);
    },
    componentDidLeave: function(){
        console.log('MyBox.componentDidLeave');
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log('MyBox.componentDidMount');
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        console.log('MyBox.componentWillUnmount');
    },
    render: function(){
        return <div>&nbsp;</div>;
    }
});
var Container = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { isShowing: false };
    },
    onButtonClicked: function(){
        this.setState({ isShowing: !this.state.isShowing });
    },
    render: function(){
        var myBox = this.state.isShowing ? <MyBox key="myBox" /> : '';
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <MyButton onButtonClicked={this.onButtonClicked} />
                <ReactTransitionGroup transitionName="hellotransition">
                    {myBox}
                </ReactTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var MyButton = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <button onClick={this.props.onButtonClicked}>Click Me</button>;
    }
});
//
React.render(<Container />, document.body);
```

Let me know if anything is unclear and I'll be happy to share what I know.

Comment: So, is it impossible to handle componentWillLeave without creating a container class, and putting the `componentWillLeave` on the child class?

Comment: @crush: the idea is that each `component` will have its own life-cycle events available to it. so a parent component will have its own `componentWillLeave` method available for it to use and child will have its own.

Comment: I have to pass all my parameters through my container component to my actual component now when making modules. It's not a lot of work, just redundant. This example helped me by the way.

Comment: Hmm. I hope you don't mean that you are _passing_ (or trying to pass) these life-cycle events down to your child component? Glad the example helped, I am also learning. :)

Comment: [**Refer to this jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/16353/) that I created. See how I first have to pass my `onAuthenticated` callback through my transition container to my actual component? That's redundancy.

Comment: I guess I should be putting the TransitionGroup around `<LoginBox/>` in my `App` component instead of making a component for the transition group. :) Knew there must be an easier way.

Comment: :) glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Without the callback, React would have no way of knowing how long to wait for your custom animation. Some clarification from one of the methods from the docs:

> **`componentWillLeave(callback)`**
>
> This is called when the child has been removed from the `ReactTransitionGroup`. Though the child has been removed, `ReactTransitionGroup` will keep it in the DOM until `callback` is called.

Imagine you want to fade out a component when it gets mounted, and you want to implement the fade-out code in pure JavaScript. When the component is unmounted, React calls `componentWillLeave`. You initiate the fade-out code (maybe using jQuery animations, or some tweening library), and when the fade-out is *done*, you call the callback to indicate that the animation is done, and then and only then will React unmount the component.