# slideUp() and slideDown() animation using React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have created a react component which consist of slideUp() and slideDown() animation. I have implemented using jQuery slideup and slidedown methods.

I have to implement this feature using react animation.

I read about **ReactTransitionGroup** and **ReactCSSTransitionGroup**. The way of explanation taught me, we can do this functionality when **DomNode** mounted to a component or unmount(Correct me if I am wrong).

My question is --> how to do slideup() and slidedown() in react way and without using jQuery.

See this jsFiddle for https://jsfiddle.net/guc3yrm1/

P.S - > Please explain me why this react animation part seems bit a difficult when compare to jQuery(I am a jQuery guy)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            slide: false,
        }
    },
    slide: function() {
        if (this.state.slide) {
            $(this.refs.slide).slideDown();
            this.setState({
                slide: false
            });
        } else {
            $(this.refs.slide).slideUp();
            this.setState({
                slide: true
            });
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <input type = "button" value = "clickme" onClick = {this.slide}/> 
                <br />
                <br />
                <div className = "slide" ref="slide" >< /div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( < Hello name = "World" / > ,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Just curious: why don't you want to use jQuery here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353966/jquery-and-reactjs-only-animations

Comment: @Chris I can do this with the help of jQuery. I am curious about how to do this in reactTransitionAPI for static content in react component. Eventually we can avoid unwanted rerender with the use of react way

Answer (score 49):

You can implement the animations in the both animations' APIs. Here is the main difference:

> ReactTransitionGroup is the API upon which ReactCSSTransitionGroup is
>   built. The main difference between the two is that
>   ReactTransitionGroup animations are written in Javascript instead of
>   CSS, and a callback is provided to be invoked when animations are
>   complete instead of relying on CSS transition events.

My conclusion is use CSS animations for the simple tasks, while Javascript for the complex ones.

For example if the  component has static height - you can implement it via CSS, as the example shows below. But if the width/height are dynamic, then you can do it with Javascript. In the Javascript example I'm using Velocity library for the animations. [It's performance better than jQuery's animations](https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation). Of course you can implement the animations by yourself, but why to reinvent the wheel?

I've implemented slideUp/slideDown with the both APIs. Check it out below.

## (CSS) Implementation via ReactCSSTransitionGroup:

```js
const CSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
const TransitionGroup = React.addons.TransitionGroup;

class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: false };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
     this.setState({ visible: ! this.state.visible });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.visible ? 'Slide up' : 'Slide down'}</button>
            <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
             { this.state.visible ? <div className='panel' /> : null }
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    }
}

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.example-enter {
    height: 0px;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

[JSFiddle - React Slide up and Slide down animation - CSS Transtion Group](https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_enev/xtbxk20g/).

---

## (Javascript) Implementation via ReactTransitionGroup:

```js
const TransitionGroup = React.addons.TransitionGroup;

class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: false };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ visible: ! this.state.visible });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.visible ? 'Slide up' : 'Slide down'}</button>
                <TransitionGroup>
                    { this.state.visible ? <Accordion /> : null }
                </TransitionGroup>
            </div>
        }
    }

    class Accordion extends React.Component {
        componentWillEnter (callback) {
            const element = this.container.getDOMNode();
            Velocity(element, 'slideDown', { duration: 300 }).then(callback);
        }

        componentWillLeave (callback) {
            const element = this.container.getDOMNode();
            Velocity(element, 'slideUp', { duration: 300 }).then(callback);
        }

        setContainer(c) {
            this.container = c;
        }

        render() {
            return <div className="panel" ref={this.setContainer.bind(this)}>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </div>
        }
    }

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.panel {
    background: green;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.4.3/velocity.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

[JSFiddle - React Slide up and Slide down animation - Javascript Transition group](https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_enev/9cLatcj5/).

---

Credits:

- [Animations with ReactTransitionGroup](https://medium.com/@cheapsteak/animations-with-reacttransitiongroup-4972ad7da286#.quoc8zsem)
- [CSS vs. JS Animation: Which is Faster?](https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation)

Comment: what if the panel doesn't have a fixed height?

Comment: .invisble {max-height: 0%; overflow: hidden;} .visible{ max-height: 100%; }

Comment: Hey, in that case we can implement it via Javascript - ReactTransitionGroup. I've updated my answer and I've added Javascript example with Velocity.

Comment: @noa-dev can you please fork my JSFiddle and make it via CSS? https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_enev/xtbxk20g/

Comment: @JordanEnev Forked and mentioned you in my reply :)

Comment: @JordanEnev I'm finding this only works if the component attribute is added as well i.e. `<CSSTransitionGroup component="div"...`

Answer (score 12):

If you (like me) came here in search for a react alternative to jQuery's `slideDown`/`slideUp`, then **[react-slidedown](https://github.com/frankwallis/react-slidedown)** seems like an easy to use react component. It's github page has a **demo** and **example code**.

Answer (score 4):

As requested by Jordan Enev i forked his JSFiddle.

Here is a solution that doesn't require React Css Transition Group whatsoever.
I am personally a fan of class-toggles. That was you can create the css animation however you like it to be.

https://jsfiddle.net/fyuh32je/3/

(whole code in the fiddle)

```
class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: 'panel' };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ visible: this.state.visible == 'panel'? 'panel visible' : 'panel' });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{!this.state.visible == 'panel' ? 'Slide up' : 'Slide down'}</button>
                <div className={this.state.visible}>
                <p>This is some dynamic content!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              </div>
        </div>
    }
}

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I know it's dirty to use the visible state variable like that, but I am at work and didn't have too much time to change too much. Note that we are using the visible class to toggle the div container with an animation.

Generally speaking. Dynamic height containers can be animated with the hacky usage of max-height attribute in css.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your effort! Actually you're hardcoding the height value of the panel, once it's visible. The idea is everything to be dynamic, i.e. the height of  the panel to be relevant of the panel's content height. Please check out my Javascript example. Also using *ReactCSSTransitionGroup* you can skip setting up manually the names of the css classes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the fixed height declaration. I updated my JS Fiddle. You can clearly see that the container behaves dynamically to its content and is being animated while opening without a fixed height. 
You can test and remove or add a few text lines.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! As you already mentioned it's a little bit a hackish way of doing it. Also you have to handle css classes names manually. For sure I'll prefer the React way of doing animations! Thanks for contribution!

Comment: @noa-dev how could I adapt your logic on the link bellow, preserving my existing click event functionality? I am still green on react. please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692961/implement-a-slidetoggle-functionality-with-react-js