# React CSSTransitionGroup not animating height, width, or top

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm trying to get a navbar to slide up and down on scroll. Pretty simple. I can get opacity no problem. But nothing else works. With anything else the navbar just appears and disappears, no animation.

I've tried this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677059/slideup-and-slidedown-animation-using-react-js) in many variations. It took adding `component='div'` to get opacity to work. I've run through a number of animation libraries only to find that they don't work. It's literally been days. I'm at a complete loss for what to try next. Maybe it's something in the CSS.

Any help would be overwhelmingly appreciated.

**Component**:

```
return (
<div>
    <CSSTransitionGroup component='div' transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500}transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
        { this.state.visible ?

            <div key='nav-container' className='pure-g nav-container' style={containerStyle} >
                    <div className='pure-u-1-24' />
                    <div className='pure-u-10-24 logo'>
                        <img style={logoStyle} src={'https://s3.amazonaws.com/philandrews/header-logo.svg'} alt='Phil Andrews Logo' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='pure-u-12-24'>
                        <Link style={linkStyle} to={'/blog'}>
                            BLOG
                        </Link>
                        <Link style={linkStyle} to={'/contact'}>
                            CONTACT
                        </Link>
                        <Link style={linkStyle} to={'/work'}>
                            WORK
                        </Link>
                    </div>
            </div>
            : null
        }

    </CSSTransitionGroup>
</div>
)
```

**Container Style:**

```
const containerStyle = {
    position: 'fixed',
    fontFamily: "'Heebo', sans-serif",
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '80px',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    zIndex: 24
}
```

**Animation CSS:**

```
.example-enter {
    height: 0px;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is CSS precedence. You have inline styles overriding your CSS rules, hence `height` is always `80px`. You also will want to set `overflow: hidden` to avoid some flashing of content.

You could either:

a) use `!important` to override the inline styles:

```css
.example-enter {
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    height: 80px !important;
    transition: height .3s ease;
}
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    height: 0px !important;
    transition: height .3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
const CSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
const Link = ({to,children}) => <a href={to}>{children}</a>;

const containerStyle = {
    position: 'fixed',
    fontFamily: "'Heebo', sans-serif",
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '80px',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    zIndex: 24
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() { super(); this.state = {} }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible})} style={{marginTop:100}}>Toggle Visible</button>

        <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeave transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
        { this.state.visible ?

            <div key='nav-container' className='pure-g nav-container' style={containerStyle} >
                    <div className='pure-u-1-24' />
                    <div className='pure-u-10-24 logo'>
                        <img  src={'https://s3.amazonaws.com/philandrews/header-logo.svg'} alt='Phil Andrews Logo' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='pure-u-12-24'>
                        <Link to={'/blog'}>
                            BLOG
                        </Link>
                        <Link to={'/contact'}>
                            CONTACT
                        </Link>
                        <Link to={'/work'}>
                            WORK
                        </Link>
                    </div>
            </div>
            : null
        }
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.example-enter {
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    height: 80px !important;
    transition: height .3s ease;
}
.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    height: 0px !important;
    transition: height .3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

- or -

b) use `max-height`, which is enforced even if `height` is greater:

```css
.example-enter {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.example-enter-active {
    max-height: 80px;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
}
.example-leave {
    max-height: 80px;
}
.example-leave-active {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
const CSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
const Link = ({to,children}) => <a href={to}>{children}</a>;

const containerStyle = {
    position: 'fixed',
    fontFamily: "'Heebo', sans-serif",
    top: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '80px',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    zIndex: 24
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() { super(); this.state = {} }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible})} style={{marginTop:100}}>Toggle Visible</button>

        <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeave transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
        { this.state.visible ?

            <div key='nav-container' className='pure-g nav-container' style={containerStyle} >
                    <div className='pure-u-1-24' />
                    <div className='pure-u-10-24 logo'>
                        <img  src={'https://s3.amazonaws.com/philandrews/header-logo.svg'} alt='Phil Andrews Logo' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='pure-u-12-24'>
                        <Link to={'/blog'}>
                            BLOG
                        </Link>
                        <Link to={'/contact'}>
                            CONTACT
                        </Link>
                        <Link to={'/work'}>
                            WORK
                        </Link>
                    </div>
            </div>
            : null
        }
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.example-enter {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.example-enter-active {
    max-height: 80px;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
}
.example-leave {
    max-height: 80px;
}
.example-leave-active {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```