# Animating text state change in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

First let me show my code:

```
import { menuContext } from '../../../../Home';
import Hamburger from '../Hamburger';

function Nav() {

    const {hamburgerToggle} = useContext(menuContext);

    let dataObject = {
        colorAbout: 'orange-rowan',
        colorContact: 'white',
        innerText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Volutpat, ullamcorper non ac fermentum dignissim diam molestie. Commodo quam sed suscipit sem. Ut aliquet neque amet, in at. Ut fermentum lectus sit tristique tincidunt viverra non.'
    }

    const [data, setData] = useState(dataObject);

    const setDataContact = () => {
        setData({
            colorAbout: 'white',
            colorContact: 'orange-rowan',
            innerText: 'jopie',
        })
    }
    const setDataAbout = () => {
        setData({
            colorAbout: 'orange-rowan',
            colorContact: 'white',
            innerText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Volutpat, ullamcorper non ac fermentum dignissim diam molestie. Commodo quam sed suscipit sem. Ut aliquet neque amet, in at. Ut fermentum lectus sit tristique tincidunt viverra non.',
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="bg-black z-50 border-r border-brokenblack-rowan w-full md:w-nav absolute left-0 h-14 md:h-full flex items-center pl-5 md:pl-0 md:justify-center">
                <Hamburger hamburger="arrowturn" />
            </div>
            <div className={`nav-transition text-xl font-light bg-black h-full w-full md:w-4/12 -left-full  opacity-0 z-40 md:z-10 absolute ${hamburgerToggle} flex flex-col justify-center`}>
                <div className={`pl-5 pr-5 md:pl-nav md:pr-65`}>
                    <ul className="mb-10">
                        <li onClick={setDataAbout} className={`cursor-pointer inline mr-5 text-${data.colorAbout}`}>about</li>
                        <li onClick={setDataContact} className={`cursor-pointer inline mr-5 text-${data.colorContact}`}>contact</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p className="text-white font-light text-base mb-10 minimum-height">
                        {data.innerText}
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" className="text-sm text-gray-rowan">cv bekijken</a>
                </div>
                <div className="absolute bottom-0 h-14 border-t border-brokenblack-rowan w-full pl-20 flex flex-col justify-center">
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

As you can see i have 2 menu items named `about` and `contact`. And when i click on either of them, the object in my state changes and so the information on my page as well. (Is this the good way to do this?).

Now what i want to do is implement a fade animation on `{data.innerText}` so when the state changes, it fades from the old text to the new text. I tried multiple things (React Spring, CSS Transition based on classes, normal CSS transitions) but i just can't wrap my head around it!

Could somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507110/implementing-transition-effects-in-react-js-when-state-changes

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achive the results you are after, is to use css transitions to fade between styles based on an "active index".

It's a different approach to your example; instead of setting a state with the current text - we set which index we should display:

```
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState();
```

Then, when clicking an item, we should  set that index to active

```
<li>
  <button
    onClick={() => setActiveIndex(1)} // 
    className="p-2 w-20 bg-blue-700"
    type="button"
  >
    1
  </button>
</li>
```

In the view, we can now conditionally apply opacity, based on if the index is active or not:

```
<div
  className={`transition duration-500 ${ activeIndex === 1 ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0" }`}
>
  This is the first index
</div>

<div
  className={`transition duration-500 ${ activeIndex === 2 ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0" }`}
>
  This is the second index
</div>
```

You can ofcourse use other transition properties as well.

**Check out an extended example in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-smoke-uzzw7?file=/src/App.js)**