# React - Show and hide slide animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on a React project for some time now. I have a board with elements on it. These elements contain images. I have a working version of it here: https://geoboard.luukwuijster.dev/ . This version is just in plain JavaScript and jQuery, but it does illustrate what I want to achieve in the new React version. When I upload an image (by pasting it using CTRL + V) I want it to be animated. It should slide in and slide back out. In the older version I am just using jQuery's slideIn and slideOut, but I am now wondering how I can achive this in React.

## I have already tried the following things:

- CSSTransition. I have tried using CSSTransition by setting the height of the element to zero and having a transition on height. This does not work because the height of the element is variable, so it should be auto. transition does not work on height: auto.
- Animate.CSS I have tried putting a slideInDown on the element, but since Animcate.CSS is using Transform, this isn't working. The Element just pops in a couple pixels above and slides down.
- jQuery's slideIn and slideOut. This is somewhat working, but just bugs out. I use `ref` to get the element, but when adding a new element to the array it animates the last element and not the first. It's also glitching a bit when animating.

## This is my code:

**Board.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Config } from 'util/config';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { AppState } from 'store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { BoardState } from 'store/board/types';
import { BoardHubService } from 'services/hubs/boardHub.service';
import { BoardElementViewModel } from 'models/BoardElementViewModel';
import { BoardViewModel } from 'models/BoardViewModel';
import { BoardElement } from './boardElement/boardElement';
import { HttpService } from 'services/http.service';
import { setActiveBoard } from 'store/board/actions';

import './board.scss'
import { mapToType } from 'helpers/helpers';

interface BoardProps {
    activeBoardState: BoardState;
    setActiveBoard: typeof setActiveBoard;
}

interface LocalBoardState {
    boardElements: Array<BoardElementViewModel>
}

class Board extends React.Component<BoardProps, LocalBoardState> {

    private config: Config;

    private httpService: HttpService;
    private boardHubService: BoardHubService;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.config = container.resolve(Config);
        this.boardHubService = container.resolve(BoardHubService);

        this.httpService = container.resolve(HttpService);

        this.state = {
            boardElements: []
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        // If there was any active board on page load...
        if (this.props.activeBoardState.boardId) {

            await this.loadBoardElements();
        }

        this.boardHubService.getConnection().on('SwitchedBoard', (response: BoardViewModel) => {
            this.setState({
                boardElements: response.elements
            });

            console.log('SwitchedBoard', this.props.activeBoardState);

            this.updateSiteTitle();
        });

        this.boardHubService.getConnection().on('ReceiveElement', (response: BoardElementViewModel) => {

            let elements = this.state.boardElements;
            elements.unshift(response);

            this.setState(() => ({
                boardElements: elements
            }))
        });

        this.boardHubService.getConnection().on('RemoveElement', (response: string) => {

            let elements = this.state.boardElements;
            let element = mapToType<BoardElementViewModel>(elements.find(x => x.id === response));
            elements.splice(elements.indexOf(element), 1);

            this.setState(() => ({
                boardElements: elements
            }))
        });
    }

    /**
     * Load the elements from the board that was already active on page load.
     */
    private async loadBoardElements() {
        await this.httpService.getWithAuthorization<Array<BoardElementViewModel>>(`/boards/${this.props.activeBoardState.boardId}/elements`)
            .then((response: Array<BoardElementViewModel>) => {
                this.setState({
                    boardElements: response
                });
            })
            .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
    }

    private updateSiteTitle() {
        if (this.props.activeBoardState.boardId != null) {
            document.title = `${this.props.activeBoardState.name} | ${this.config.siteName}`;
        }
        else {
            document.title = this.config.siteName;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.activeBoardState.boardId != null
                    ?
                    <div className="board-elements">

                        {this.state.boardElements.map((element: BoardElementViewModel, index) => {
                            return (
                                <BoardElement
                                    key={index}
                                    id={element.id}
                                    // TODO: Use number from server
                                    number={element.elementNumber}
                                    user={element.user}
                                    direction={element.direction}
                                    note={element.note}
                                    imageId={element.imageId}
                                    createdAt={element.createdAt}
                                />
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>

                    :
                    <div className="select-board-instruction">
                        <h1>Please select or create a board.</h1>
                    </div>
                }
            </>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
    activeBoardState: state.activeBoard
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setActiveBoard })(Board);
```

**BoardElement.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserViewModel } from 'models/UserViewModel';
import { Direction } from 'models/Direction';

import './boardElement.scss';
import { dateToReadableString } from 'helpers/helpers';
import { Config } from 'util/config';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { HttpService } from 'services/http.service';
import { CSSTransition, Transition } from 'react-transition-group';

import $ from 'jquery'

interface BoardElementProps {
    id: string;
    number: number;
    user: UserViewModel;
    // TODO: Use direction Enum
    direction?: Direction;
    note?: string;
    imageId?: string;
    createdAt: Date;
}

export class BoardElement extends React.Component<BoardElementProps> {

    private config: Config;
    private httpService: HttpService;
    private ref: any;

    constructor(props: BoardElementProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            height: 0
        }

        this.config = container.resolve(Config);
        this.httpService = container.resolve(HttpService);
    }

    getReadableDirection(direction: Direction) {
        // TODO: Richtingen vertalen
        switch (direction) {
            case Direction.North: return 'Noord';
            case Direction.NorthEast: return 'Noordoost';
            case Direction.East: return 'Oost';
            case Direction.SouthEast: return 'Zuidoost';
            case Direction.South: return 'Zuid';
            case Direction.SouthWest: return 'Zuidwest';
            case Direction.West: return 'West';
            case Direction.NorthWest: return 'Noordwest';
        }
    }

    removeElement() {
        $(this.ref).slideUp(200);

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.httpService.deleteWithAuthorization(`/boards/elements/${this.props.id}`).then(() => {

            }, (error) => {
                console.warn(error);
            });
        }, 250);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this.ref).slideDown(200);
        }, 500);
    }

    render() {

        let style: any = { display: "none" };

        return (

            <div ref={element => this.ref = element} style={style}>
                <div className="board-element" data-element-id={this.props.id}>
                    <div className="board-element-header">
                        <span className="board-element-number">{this.props.number}</span>
                        <span className="board-element-creator">{this.props.user.username}</span>
                        <i className="fas fa-trash ml-auto delete-icon" onClick={() => this.removeElement()}></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="board-element-body">
                        {this.props.imageId
                            ? <img className="board-element-image" src={`${this.config.apiUrl}/content/${this.props.imageId}`} />
                            : <p className="board-element-message">{this.props.note}</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="board-element-footer">

                        {this.props.direction &&
                            <div className="board-element-direction">
                                <i className="fas fa-location-arrow direction mr-2"></i>{this.getReadableDirection(this.props.direction)}
                            </div>
                        }

                        <time className="board-element-timestamp" dateTime={this.props.createdAt.toString()}>{dateToReadableString(this.props.createdAt)}</time>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

## UPDATE:

https://gyazo.com/6dfb3db8cbd29da0f4f52af33c545421

This clip might illustrate my problem better. Look closly at the number in the corner of the elements. When I paste a new image the animation is not applied to the new image, but rather the last image in the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [slideUp() and slideDown() animation using React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677059/slideup-and-slidedown-animation-using-react-js)

Comment: @dorukerenaktas No, this does not answer my question. The answer provided in the question you linked is outdated. I cannot use the css implementation as I explained in my original post and the javascript implementation uses React.addons.TransitionGroup what isn't part of React anymore. The new TransitionGroup works different and I cannot get it to work. I will add a short clip demonstrating what I have right now. (with the code from my post)

Comment: How about animating `max-height` instead of `height` in css?

Comment: Haha, ik zie opeens nederlandse woorden in de code. hey mede kaaskop!

Comment: @YouriKoeman It works, but it works just like you see in the clip I added to my question. The new element gets added to the board, but the last element is animated. 

En hey hallo daar ;)

Comment: I begin to feel like I should close this question and ask about animating the first element in an array because all solutions have the same problem in common. It works, but the wrong element gets the animation. :/

Comment: Make sure you set the state of the element during  `contruct()`  and `componentDidMount()` and use those values.

Comment: are you using some kind of column system? it may be that mounting it to a new column causes this, does the problem persist when you do this the 4th time?

Comment: @YouriKoeman Yes, I set state correctly. That's not the issue. And I am not using columns. It's just flexbox.

Comment: Can you update the code to reflect your current state?